# Validation error(Data Annotations) not working in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have a radio button group and a validation to ensure atleast one of the options are selected. But my validation does not work on the view but they are caught in Model.Valid in the controller. How do I get it to show on the view like other validation errors without having to add a message in the controller on Model.IsValid fail?

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="" class="control-label">Role</label>
      <div>
         @foreach (var availableGroup in availableGroups)
          {
             <div class="radio">
                 <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="Group" value="@availableGroup" @defaulted/>
                                @availableGroup
                  </label>
             </div>
           }
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Group)
       </div>
</div>
```

Model :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Group must be selected")]
[Display(Name = "Group")]
public string Group { get; set; }
```

Do I have to use Jquery on button click and then verify manually? I have seen ModelState.AddModelError() which will still require me to submit the action method. Is there something I can change in the way I am binding the radio buttons?

EDIT 1 : The Html equivalent for one of the options as seen in developer tool is

```
<label>
      <input type="radio" name="Group" value="Group 1">
            Group 1
</label>
```

EDIT 2: I already have data annotations working and it works fine with the other required textboxes. It is only in the radio button list that I have the issue.

Comment: Why are you creating your html manually - use the `RadioButtonFor()` method - `<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Group, availableGroup, new { id = "" })<span>@availableGroup</span></label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I solved the issue. I checked how the HTML code will be for a Html.CheckboxFor and tried to mimic it to obtain the result.

```
<div class="radio">
     <label>
           <input type="radio" name="Group" data-val="true" data-val-required="Group must be selected" value="@availableGroup" @defaulted/>
                            @availableGroup
     </label>
</div>
```

I had to add the data-val and data-val-required Attribute to get it to work.

Answer (score -2):

I Hope i got the solution to your problem,

**Solution:**

Add the following validation related jquery files to the view

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/anyversion")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
```

or add like below , if you are using bundles

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Answer to question:

Do I have to use Jquery on button click and then verify manually?

No , By default Data annotation handles both the client and server validations.

Hope it will be helpful for you,kindly let me know your thoughts

Thanks
Karthik

Comment: I already have those and the data annotation is working for simple textboxes.

Comment: oh sorry! just now i noticed, you should bind the model with the radiobuttonlist for the validation to work. Here is the example:           
 Yes
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TermsAndConditions, "True", model.TermsAndConditions == true ? new { Checked = "checked" } : null)
No
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TermsAndConditions, "False", model.TermsAndConditions == false ? new { Checked = "checked" } : null).   Useful link:https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1060015/model-binding-radio-button-list-in-Asp-net-mvc